# In a RESTful HTTP request for search results, if there are no results, should I return an empty array or a 404 error code?

Tags: rest, http, search

In a RESTful HTTP request for search results, if there are no results, should I return an empty array or a an error code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return an empty array, because the resource (result collection) exists, but it is empty.